# Linking two webapps user accounts ...

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I somehow managed to register two separate accounts on webapps.stackexchange.com.

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/4578/sabre23t
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6575/sabre23t

The former via FB login, the latter via myopenid login. I couldn't seem to find a way to link them together again. Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a different OpenID for the second account so as far as the system is concerned they are two separate accounts.

You haven't posted anything with the second so I could just delete it rather than merging the accounts.

Do you want me to e-mail you the openID you used for the first account? If so add a comment to this answer. I can also delete the second account if that's what you want.

Comment: ChrisF, I would appreciate you deleting the second account, and emailing me the myopenid for the first account. TQVM. ;-)

Comment: @sabre32t - it looks like the second account has already been deleted/merged (even I can't see the page when I click on the link). I'll e-mail you the openid (or at least enough of it for you to identify it) tonight (GMT). Though the fact that you have posted this question and commented using that account indicates you had the right details at one point.

Comment: Thanks. It's now sorted out, and I have only one account. ;-)